# Oracle sql developer connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to oracle DB using Oracle SQL Developer (Version 3.0.04)
Connection parameters follows,

host : 
port : 
user : xxxx
password : sssss
service name : asdf.somedomain.com

When connecting I am getting the following error

Unsupported verifier type.

I am able to ping the host so no network problem.
I have another server in the same network which works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

It might be the issue with the thin Java driver. Try checking Tools-Preferences-Database-Advanced-Use OCI/Thick driver.

Answer (score 1):

For me adding the below line in ***sqldeveloper.conf*** works fine.You can find this conf file inside **\sqldeveloper\bin** directory.

```
AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3
```